# 500 Internal Server Error in flask predict page

Tags: flask

```
class Prediction(FlaskForm):
    Make = SelectField(
        "Make",
        validators=[InputRequired()],
        choices=MAKE,
    )
    make_year = IntegerField(
        "Year of Manufacture",
        validators=[InputRequired(), NumberRange(min=0)]
    )
    seating_capacity = IntegerField(    
        "Seating Capacity",
        validators=[InputRequired(), NumberRange(min=0)]
    )
    fuel_tank_capacity = IntegerField(
        "Fuel Tank Capacity",
        validators=[InputRequired(), NumberRange(min=0)]
    )
    cc_displacement = IntegerField(
        "CC Displacement",
        validators=[InputRequired(), NumberRange(min=0)]
    )

    mileage_run = FloatField(
        "Mileage run", validators=[InputRequired(), NumberRange(min=0)]
    )

    power = FloatField(
        "power", validators=[InputRequired(), NumberRange(min=0)]
    )

    torque = FloatField(
        "torque", validators=[InputRequired(), NumberRange(min=0)]
    )

    mileage = FloatField(
        "mileage", validators=[InputRequired(), NumberRange(min=0)]
    )
    no_of_owners  = SelectField(
        "no_of_owners",
        validators=[InputRequired()],
        choices=NO_OF_OWNERS,
    )
    emission  = SelectField(
        "emission Type",
        validators=[InputRequired()],
        choices=EMISSIONS,
    )

    fuel_Type  = SelectField(
        "fuel Type",
        validators=[InputRequired()],
        choices=FUEL_TYPE,
    )
    transmission_Type  = SelectField(
        "transmission_Type Type",
        validators=[InputRequired()],
        choices=TRANSMISSION_TYPE,
    )


    actual_price = FloatField(
        "Actual Listing Price in SGD (Optional)", validators=[Optional(), NumberRange(min=0)]
    )

    link = URLField("Link to Listing (Optional)", validators=[Optional(), URL()])

    submit = SubmitField("Submit")
```

html(i did specify method = "POST"):

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="px-5 pb-4">
    <h1 class="display-5 fw-bold text-left">
        Make a prediction
    </h1>
    <p class="lead">
        Simply type down the details of the listing in question, and our AI model will make a prediction for you!
    </p>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="px-5 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 mx-auto">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <form name="predictionForm" method="POST" action="/predict" novalidate>
                    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        {{ form.make_year.label(class_='form-label') }}
                        {{ form.make_year(class_='form-control')}}
                        {% for error in form.make_year.errors %}
                        <span class="text-danger">{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        {{ form.seating_capacity.label(class_='form-label') }}
                        {{ form.seating_capacity(class_='form-control')}}
                        {% for error in form.seating_capacity.errors %}
                        <span class="text-danger">{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        {{ form.fuel_tank_capacity.label(class_='form-label') }}
                        {{ form.fuel_tank_capacity(class_='form-control')}}
                        {% for error in form.fuel_tank_capacity.errors %}
                        <span class="text-danger">{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        {{ form.cc_displacement.label(class_='form-label') }}
                        {{ form.cc_displacement(class_='form-control')}}
                        {% for error in form.cc_displacement.errors %}
                        <span class="text-danger">{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        {{ form.mileage_run.label(class_='form-label') }}
                        {{ form.mileage_run(class_='form-control')}}
                        {% for error in form.mileage_run.errors %}
                        <span class="text-danger">{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        {{ form.make.label(class_='form-label') }}
                        {{ form.make(class_='form-control')}}
                        {% for error in form.make.errors %}
                        <span class="text-danger">{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        {{ form.power.label(class_='form-label') }}
                        {{ form.power(class_='form-control')}}
                        {% for error in form.power.errors %}
                        <span class="text-danger">{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        {{ form.torque.label(class_='form-label') }}
                        {{ form.torque(class_='form-control')}}
                        {% for error in form.torque.errors %}
                        <span class="text-danger">{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        {{ form.mileage.label(class_='form-label') }}
                        {{ form.mileage(class_='form-control')}}
                        {% for error in form.mileage.errors %}
                        <span class="text-danger">{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        {{ form.no_of_owners.label(class_='form-label') }}
                        {{ form.no_of_owners(class_='form-control')}}
                        {% for error in form.no_of_owners.errors %}
                        <span class="text-danger">{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        {{ form.emission.label(class_='form-label') }}
                        {{ form.emission(class_='form-control')}}
                        {% for error in form.emission.errors %}
                        <span class="text-danger">{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        {{ form.fuel_type.label(class_='form-label') }}
                        {{ form.fuel_type(class_='form-control')}}
                        {% for error in form.fuel_type.errors %}
                        <span class="text-danger">{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        {{ form.transmission_type.label(class_='form-label') }}
                        {{ form.transmission_type(class_='form-control')}}
                        {% for error in form.transmission_type.errors %}
                        <span class="text-danger">{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>




                    <div class="form-check">
                        {{ form.actual_price.label(class_='form-check-label') }}
                        {{ form.actual_price(class_='form-check-input' )}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        {{ form.link.label(class_='form-label') }}
                        {{ form.link(class_='form-control') }}
                        {% for error in form.link.errors %}
                        <span class="text-danger">{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            {{ form.submit(class_='btn btn-success') }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="py-5 px-5 {%if results %} col-lg-6 col-sm-12 {%else%} d-none {%endif%}">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title fw-bold">The predicted car fee is...</h5>
                <p class="card-text text-center fs-5">SGD {{price | default(0)|round(precision=2) }} per car
                    {% if actual_price %}
                    which is
                    {% if same %}
                    the same
                    {% else %}
                    ${{ price_diff | round(precision=2) }}
                    {% if actual_price < price %} more {% else %} less {% endif %} {% endif %} than the listing price.
                        {% endif %} </p>
                        <a href="#explain" class="card-link">Why?</a>
                        <a href="/history" class="card-link">See history</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% if results %}
<hr class="my-5">
<div class="px-5 row my-5" id="explain">
    <h2 class="display-6 fw-bold text-left">Prediction Report</h2>
    <p class="lead">
        Want to know how the model predicted the price? See our breakdown below...
    </p>
    <div class="col-lg-4 order-1 mt-5 pt-5">
        <h3>What features does the model care about?</h3>
        <p class="lead">
            Generally, the model views the following factors as being the most important: (in order)
        </p>
        <ol>
            <li>Room Type</li>
            <li>Number of People that can be Accomodated</li>
            <li>The Mininum Number of Nights Visitors can Stay</li>
            <li>Number of Bathrooms and Beds</li>
            <li>Neighborhood</li>
            <li>Ammenities</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <figure class="col-lg-8 order-2 text-center">
        <!-- Model Interpreation Here-->
        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/feature_importances.png')}}"
            alt="Feature importances Plot of Model" class="img img-fluid">
        <figcaption>Feature Importances Plot of the Model</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
<div class="px-5 my-5 row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 order-sm-1 order-lg-2 mt-5 pt-5">
        <h3>How accurate is the model?</h3>
        <p class="lead">The model has a mean absolute error of $36 (on an independent test set), meaning that we can
            expect the model to be off by around $36 on average. The root mean squared error of the model is $70.90, suggesting that the
            model does not do as well on outlier listings.</p>
    </div>
    <figure class="col-lg-8 order-sm-2 order-lg-2 text-center">
        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/model_residual_plot.png')}}" alt="Residual Plot of Model"
            class="img img-fluid">
        <figcaption>Residual Plot of the Model. Residuals = Actual - Predicted</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>

{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Routes.py

```
from traceback import format_exc
import traceback 
@app.route("/predict", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def predict():
    try:    
        print("Entering predict function")
        pred_form = Prediction()
        show_result = False
        results = {}
        print("Entering predict function")
        if request.method == "POST":
            print('Form submitted as POST')
            if not pred_form.validate_on_submit():
                print('Form validation failed')
                raise BadRequest("Form validation failed")
            # Extract form data
            make_year = pred_form.make_year.data
            seating_capacity = pred_form.seating_capacity.data
            fuel_tank_capacity = pred_form.fuel_tank_capacity.data
            cc_displacement = pred_form.cc_displacement.data
            mileage_run = pred_form.mileage_run.data
            make = pred_form.make.data
            power = pred_form.power.data
            torque = pred_form.torque.data
            mileage = pred_form.mileage.data
            no_of_owners = pred_form.no_of_owners.data
            emission = pred_form.emission.data
            fuel_type = pred_form.fuel_Type.data
            transmission_type = pred_form.transmission_Type.data
            actual_price = pred_form.actual_price.data
            link = pred_form.link.data

            # Validate form data
            assert make_year >= 0, "Year of manufacture must be greater than or equal to zero"
            assert seating_capacity >= 0, "Seating capacity must be greater than or equal to zero"
            assert fuel_tank_capacity >= 0, "Fuel tank capacity must be greater than or equal to zero"
            assert cc_displacement >= 0, "CC displacement must be greater than or equal to zero"
            assert mileage_run >= 0, "Mileage run must be greater than or equal to zero"
            assert power >= 0, "Power must be greater than or equal to zero"
            assert torque >= 0, "Torque must be greater than or equal to zero"
            assert mileage >= 0, "Mileage must be greater than or equal to zero"
            assert make in MAKE, "Make is invalid"
            assert no_of_owners in NO_OF_OWNERS, "Number of owners is invalid"
            assert emission in EMISSIONS, "Emission type is invalid"
            assert fuel_type in FUEL_TYPE, "Fuel type is invalid"
            assert transmission_type in TRANSMISSION_TYPE, "Transmission type is invalid"
            assert type(actual_price) in {type(None), float, int}, "Actual price should be a number or None"

            if actual_price is not None:
                assert actual_price > 0, "Actual price should be greater than 0"

            # Create entry_params DataFrame
            entry_params = pd.DataFrame({
                "Make": [make],
                "Make_Year": [make_year],
                "Mileage_Run": [mileage_run],
                "No_of_Owners": [no_of_owners],
                "Seating_Capacity": [seating_capacity],
                "Fuel_Tank_Capacity(L)": [fuel_tank_capacity],
                "CC_Displacement": [cc_displacement],
                "Power(BHP)": [power],
                "Torque(Nm)": [torque],
                "Mileage(kmpl)": [mileage],
                "Emission": [emission],
                "Fuel_Type": [fuel_type],
                "Transmission_Type": [transmission_type],
            })

            # Make prediction
            result = ai_model.predict(entry_params)
            show_result = True
            results = {"price": result[0], "actual_price": actual_price}
            difference = None

            if actual_price is not None:
                difference = float(actual_price - result[0])
                results["price_diff"] = abs(difference)
                results["same"] = results["price_diff"] < 0.05  # Account for floating-point imprecision

            # Create new entry
            new_entry = Entry(
                make=make,
                make_year=make_year,
                mileage_run=mileage_run,
                no_of_owners=no_of_owners,
                seating_capacity=seating_capacity,
                fuel_tank_capacity=fuel_tank_capacity,
                cc_displacement=cc_displacement,
                power=power,
                torque=torque,
                mileage=mileage,
                emission=emission,
                fuel_Type=fuel_type,
                transmission_Type=transmission_type,
                actual_price=actual_price,
                link=link,
                prediction=float(result[0]),
                created=dt.utcnow(),
                user_id=session["user_id"],
                difference=difference,
            )

            # Add entry to the database
            add_entry(new_entry)
            
            # Rest of your code for processing form data and making predictions
            print('Form validated successfully')

        print("Exiting predict function")
    except BadRequest as e:
        flash(f"Form validation failed. Please try again!", "danger")
        app.logger.error(f"BadRequest: {str(e)}\n{traceback.format_exc()}")
    except IntegrityError as e:
        print(f"Integrity error during registration: {str(e)}")
        flash("Email address already in use. Please choose a different one.", "danger")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Unexpected error during registration: {str(e)}")
        flash("Failed to register account. Please try again later.", "danger")

    return render_template(
        "predict.html",
        form=pred_form,
        title="CarEconomist | Make a Prediction",
        results=show_result,
        **results,
    )
```

but im getting 500 Internal Server Error
Looks like something went wrong!
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application

, and my terminal could not show any error, i am very perplexed by this situation

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2023 15:11:37] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2023 15:11:37] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2023 15:11:37] "GET /static/images/20945765.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2023 15:11:37] "GET /static/images/Wavy_Tech-20_Single-08.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2023 15:11:37] "GET /static/images/icon.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
Entering predict function
Entering predict function
Exiting predict function
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2023 15:11:39] "GET /predict HTTP/1.1" 500 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2023 15:11:39] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2023 15:11:39] "GET /static/images/11132.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2023 15:11:39] "GET /static/images/icon.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

Whats the problem here, i tried printing out error handling and apparetly the form couldnt show beacuse the method wasnt "POST" thats why it did not continue the if block

Comment: @foobar test test test potato I manage to solve that one but im getting the same error here in the predict page